# Multiplying two BigDouble values

Tags: .net, math, biginteger

I'm trying to make a "BigDouble" structure in .NET. A BigDouble number has a BigInteger integral part and a double fractional part.

Implementing addition and substraction are straightforward, but how do I do multiplication/division? The problem is that I couldn't find a way to multiply a BigInteger with a double. What should I do?

Remember: I need an exact floor and an approximate fractional part.

Comment: Sorry, but you will not be able to multiply a BigInteger and a double and get an exact integer part. We can't always have what we want.

Comment: You can "convert" the double to 2**x * (a/b), where x, a, and b are appropriately sized integers and proceed from there.

Comment: I should advise you that this simply isn't a good idea. You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a double is and how it works. A double represents a value with granularity appropriate for its magnitude. By pinning it to fraction of 1, you are simply throwing away the magnitude component of the double. Since your fractional portion is always of a set magitude, use another integer type value instead (unsigned). It's representative value would be the value divided by the maximum value for that integer. This gives you values between 0 and 1, as desired for your fractional component.

Answer (score 0):

A [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a fixed number of mantiassa bits, and an exponent. According to IEEE specs, the mantiassa will have 52 bit, and the bis before the decimal point is omitted but will always be 1. So in effect you have at least 53 bit of information past the decimal point. If you are lucky and the fractional part is small, you might have more resolution, but that seems unlikely if the integral part is non-zero.

Therefore one solution would be multiplying the fractional part by 2<sup>53</sup> and rounding it to an integer. Then you can compute with these scaled values, use them to form bigger integers, and scale back afterwards. If you want to avoid data loss at all costs, you'll have to determine the exponent of the `double` number and scale accordingly. I know some functions in other languages, like [`Math.getExponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#getExponent%28double%29) in Java or [`ilogb`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ilogb) in C. I would guess that there is something similar in .net, but I don't know about it.

But this whole observation tells me (and might also tell you) that a `double` probably isn't the appopriate way to store the fractional part. The strength of `double` is its floating point: you can store both extremely small and extremely large values using changing exponents. In your application, however, you'll be storing values from the range [0,1) with about equal probability (or so I assume). Thus the main strength of `double` is not being used. I guess you might be better off using fixed precision based on `BigInteger`. I suggest using 64 bit past the decimal point. The storage requirement will be the same as in your approach, since a `double` takes 64 bit. But in most cases the accuracy will be increased by about 11 bit, since you can use all 64 bit for useful digits, instead of only 53 in your approach. And performance will be a lot better as well, since you don't have to convert between formats.